# Linux permission, what is the X?

Tags: linux, permissions

If I set 751 to a directory, the permission are: `drwxr-x--x`

the "x" what does it mean? If i set that permission means anyone could access to this directory but ONLY the owner and the GROUP could read the contents?

Let me know, thank you

Comment: This question would probably be more appropriate to be asked on http://superuser.com; I'm quite surprised it was just "closed" by moderators, instead of being moved there.

Answer (score 12):

The execute 'x' permission, when set for a directory, grants the ability to traverse its tree in order to access files or subdirectories, but not see the content of files inside the directory (unless read 'r' is set). (*)

So in your example, owner, group and others can do anything, group can `cd` into the directory and `ls` (read the list of the files within), others can just `cd` into the directory to access subdirectories, but that's quite an useless permission without "read".

(*) See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_permissions#Permissions

Comment: If `others` are able to guess the general structure of the directory tree, with the `x` permission and a good dictionary they could still obtain a list of some of the files in the directory.

Answer (score 10):

The x means you can `cd` to the directory. The r means you can `ls` the directory.

Comment: hehe yeah, as described by a user, not a creator

Answer (score 5):

It means 'execute' permission. For a directory it has a more interesting meaning. Execute permission on a directory means you can list the files in that directory. See [here](http://www.dartmouth.edu/~rc/help/faq/permissions.html). From the link I posted:

*Remember that to read a file, you need execute access to the directory it is in AND read access to the file itself. To write a file, your need execute access to the directory AND write access to the file.*

Answer (score 3):

the x means "executable".

in your example, the owner can read an write into the directory, the group users can only read, but everyone can go inside.